# SOQL Injection Vulnerability

Tags: security-review

In security scan am getting error as **"SOQL Injection Vulnerability"**  and also the note as **"The query is user controllable"**

```
string query = 'SELECT '+ queryFields +' From '+MFNameSpaceUtil.PrependNS('MobiForm_Field__c')+' WHERE ';
    return query;
```

This is my query and doesn't have any idea what would cause the SOQL injection here. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: This appears to be the same kind of vulnerability as a SQL injection vulnerability. You should read up on them. If `queryFields` comes from any user controlled input (even a web request from a browser), then a malicious user could craft it to perform arbitrary operations on the DB.

Comment: That is not a valid query. You will never be able to run `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE` since your query cannot end with that keyword.

Comment: @jpmc26 No nothing is from user input, queryFields are all fields in that object and calling this method and returning the formed query , thanks

Comment: @AdrianLarson no am just calling this method and returning the formed query, and later adding the wherecondtion with this query , thanks

Comment: @jpmc26 "MobiForm_Field__c"--?MFNameSpaceUtil.PrependNS('MobiForm_Field__c') is for namespace. A doubt came for me is this because hardCoding of ObjectName(above) - should I assign it to a string and pass it ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Long Story:**

Quoting examples from apex [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm):

```
// User supplied value: name = Bob 
// Query string
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (IsDeleted = false and Name like '%Bob%')


However, what if the user provides unexpected input, such as:

// User supplied value for name: test%') OR (Name LIKE '

SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (IsDeleted = false AND Name LIKE '%test%') OR (Name LIKE '%')
```

To fix this you can either use static SOQL and re-write your SOQL as below

To prevent a SOQL injection attack, avoid using dynamic SOQL queries. Instead, use **static queries** and binding variables. The vulnerable example above can be re-written using static SOQL as follows:

```
public class SOQLController { 
    public String name { 
        get { return name;} 
        set { name = value;} 
    } 
    public PageReference query() { 
        String queryName = '%' + name + '%';
        queryResult = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE 
           (IsDeleted = false and Name like :queryName)];
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

For **dynamic SOQL** use `String strEsc = String.escapeSingleQuotes(str);`//str is your searchspec  from UI

> This method adds the escape character () to all single quotation
>   marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures
>   that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings,
>   instead of database commands.

**For your use case:**

You seem to be constructing the SOQL dynamically. your issue could be with your where clause if the bind variable for it comes from UI.

Comment: so you are saying nothing is wrong with the above code, and it might be from the where clause below ?? Is there any specific place where I should use String strEsc = String.escapeSingleQuotes(str); can use for all variables in dynamic SOQL right ??

Answer (score 8):

One further observation is that dynamic SOQL *does* support simple (not dotted expressions or method calls) [bind variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) that also protect against SOQL injection.

So for some dynamic SOQL cases you can use do something like this:

```
 String nameLike = '%' + nameSearchField +'%';

 String query = 'select ... from ... where Name like :nameLike';
```

that is a little cleaner than concatenating in `String.escapeSingleQuotes` calls.